# Error while calling for loop inside awk command

Tags: unix, awk

> The snippet reads as below:

```
echo -n "Filename: "
read filename
echo -n "Data Fields? "
read -a ar
awk -F '[[:space:]][[:space:]]+' 'BEGIN{OFS = "--"} {for val in "${ar[@]}" printf $val }' $filename
```

> ar is an array i am reading, filename is name of a file i am reading too.
>
> The file looks as below :

```
100  Thomas  Manager    Sales       $5,000

200  Jason   Developer  Technology  $5,500

300  Sanjay  Sysadmin   Technology  $7,000

400  Nisha   Manager    Marketing   $9,500

500  Randy   DBA        Technology  $6,000
```

> What i am trying to do is, accept the filename from user, also take the field number he wants to display, and then scan the file and produce the output accordingly.
>
> The array "ar" contains the field numbers, like 1,2,3.
>
> Input is as below:

```
$ sh awk_prac.sh

Filename: employee.txt

Data Fields: 2 3
```

> Now according to  the input i gave above, the output should look like below:

```
Thomas  Manager 

Jason   Developer 

Sanjay  Sysadmin 

Nisha   Manager 

Randy   DBA
```

> But everytime i run the code, it shows a syntax error pointing under "val" after for.

```
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN{OFS = "--"} {for val in "${ar[@]}" printf $val }
awk: cmd. line:1:                        ^ syntax error
```

> Can  anyone point out the mistake. *#i_am_new_to_this#*

Comment: That's awk script, not shell script. Same as if you put a Python script inside your shell script -- it has to follow Python syntax, not shell syntax; in this case, your code needs to be in awk syntax (and can't reference shell variables unless you pass them into awk).

Comment: BTW, please paste your errors as text, not screenshots. Screenshots aren't searchable, can render very badly on screens with different DPI, can't have code copied-and-pasted, can be ambiguous if your problems are caused by hidden characters or characters that look similar to each other, etc.

Comment: If you provided an example of your input and desired output, we could perhaps tell you how to solve your problem without using `awk` at all.

Comment: ...awk is a different language, not part of the shell specification -- so you should be using the awk tag on your question.

Comment: Vishal, what is contained in the `ar` array, and what makes you think you need awk to iterate over it?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you,  i  recognized my mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is explained in the comments under your question (awk is not shell), here's how to solve it:

```
$ cat tst.sh
echo -n "Filename: "
read filename
echo -n "Data Fields? "
read fields
awk -v fields="$fields" 'BEGIN{n=split(fields,f)} {for (i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%s%s", $(f[i]), (i<n?OFS:ORS)}' "$filename"

$ ./tst.sh
Filename: file
Data Fields? 2 3
Thomas Manager

Jason Developer

Sanjay Sysadmin

Nisha Manager

Randy DBA
```

Comment: Thank so much for your help,  i understood my mistake.  But i have one query, in the syntax, **n=split(fields,f)**, n is storing the length of  f  which has the splitted values. So, is this happening internally??

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `happening internally`, sorry. `split()` is a function that returns a value, and the variable `n` is being set to that value, that's all. It's no different than `n=7`.

Comment: yes that answers my question. i just wanted to know what it is returning. but thank you very much for solving the problem.